# Unable to Consume retrofit REST API, Getting IllegalStateException: Please help me investigate

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am a bit new to retrofit and android, so I am really embarrassed

See below error I get from Retrofit when I try to consume an API with the structure below

### The Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Please advice me on the way to consume the API without getting the above error.

See my code below

### Retrofit client instance

```
public static Retrofit getLogInRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LOG_IN_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

### Login Data Service

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface GetLogInDataService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<UserOutputObj> getServiceData(@Body LoginInputObj input);
}
```

### actual implementation

```
                GetLogInDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getLogInRetrofitInstance().create(GetLogInDataService.class);
                Call<UserOutputObj> call = service.getServiceData(myLoginInp);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<UserOutputObj>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UserOutputObj> call, Response<UserOutputObj> response) {
                        UserOutputObj finalOutput = response.body();
                        assert finalOutput != null;
                        UserInfo user = finalOutput.getUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: user:" + user);
                        Login_Token = finalOutput.getToken();
                        Login_Message = finalOutput.getMessage();
                        Login_status = finalOutput.getStatus();
                        if (Login_status) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: status is Successful");
                            type = user.getType();
                            name = user.getFullname();
                            dob = user.getDob();
                            city = user.getCity();
                            email = user.getEmail();
                            id = String.valueOf(user.getId());
                            gender = user.getGender();
                            rating = user.getRating();
                            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Login_Token: " + Login_Token);

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: status is false");
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: VERIFY: " + Login_status);
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Login_Message: " + Login_Message);
                        server_check = true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserOutputObj> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: AN ERROR OCCURRED");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Cause " + t.getCause());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: getMessage " + t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

### log output

```
 D/LOGIN: onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure
D/LOGIN: onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure
D/LOGIN: onFailure: AN ERROR OCCURRED
 D/LOGIN: onFailure: Cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

### JSON FAILURE RESPONSE

```
{
    "UserOutputObject": {
        "response": "0",
        "status": false,
        "response_text": "user does not exists",
        "message": "Number Not exist",
        "response_Code": 400
    }
}
```

### JSON SUCCESS RESPONSE

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Login Succesful",
        "token": "160444ef2fe0321-12P28071e2d6934764",
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2020-11-03T19:40:34.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-03T19:40:34.000000Z",
            "fullname": "Mr Guy 4",
            "email": "mekefefeghe@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2020-11-03T21:52:01.941539Z",
            "type": "Customer",
            "father_name": null,
            "gender": "male",
            "dob": "1983/01/26",
            "number": "19077834474589",
            "city": "Yaba",
            "state": "Lagos",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "address": "No 500 Correct address street",
            "status": "",
            "rating": 0,
            "token_id": "",
            "reg_date": "2020-11-03 19:40:34"
        },
        "response_Code": 200
    }
}
```

### serialized object

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserOutputObj implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String response;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String response_text;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UserInfo user;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean status;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int response_Code;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String message;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String msg;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String token;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int zero;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserOutputObj{" +
                "response='" + response + '\'' +
                ", response_text='" + response_text + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", response_Code=" + response_Code +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", msg='" + msg + '\'' +
                ", token='" + token + '\'' +
                ", zero=" + zero +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Please advice me on the way to consume the API as I have been cracking my head over this for a week

Comment: Right now I don't have time to try to reproduce the error. The first thing that I see is that your UserOutputObj class is wrong. You have response at the same level than the rest of the fields and in the json you have an object response and inside it the rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much,

I modified the response object to be serialized and it works